# Mute button greyed out - Any app replacement

Tags: cyanogenmod

All,

I have a redmi 1s which I have flashed with cyanogen mod 12.1. All is well except, when I am in a call, mute button is greyed out.

This is a pain for me as I am a part of various conference calls for hours during any weekday and I cant stay without muting always.

Any solution to this in terms of replacement or tweaking my cyanogenmod?

It would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing the cache and data of the Dialler app. If not find the Dialler app under Setting > All apps > Dialler > Clear Cache and Clear Data. Restart you phone and check.

If the problem persists, then you can try a third party app like [Muted Conference Calls](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.muted)